# While loop only operating on first line of file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a while loop that should iterate over a text file but stops at the first line and I can't figure out why. My code is below.

```
while read hadoop_accounts; do
        if ! grep "no lock no remove"; then
                echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}"
                echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}" >> missing_no_lock_no_remove.txt
        fi
done < hadoop_accounts.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `grep` is run with no explicit redirection or file to read, it reads stdin. **All** of stdin. The same stdin your `while read` loop is reading from.

Thus, with all your stdin consumed by `grep`, there's nothing left for the next `read` command to consume.

---

The easy approach (and much better for performance) is to do the substring check internal to the shell, and not bother starting up a new copy of `grep` per line processed at all:

```
while IFS= read -r hadoop_accounts; do
        if ! [[ $hadoop_accounts = *"no lock no remove"* ]]; then
                echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}"
                echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}" >&3
        fi
done < hadoop_accounts.txt 3>> missing_no_lock_no_remove.txt
```

Note also that we're only opening the output file once, not re-opening it every single time we want to write a single line.

---

If you *really* want to call `grep` over and over and over with only a single line of input each time, though, you *can* do that:

```
while IFS= read -r hadoop_accounts; do
        if ! grep "no lock no remove" <<<"$hadoop_accounts"; then
                echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}"
                echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}" >&3
        fi
done < hadoop_accounts.txt 3>> missing_no_lock_no_remove.txt
```

---

Or, even better than either of the above, you can just run `grep` a single time over the entire input file and read its output in the loop:

```
while IFS= read -r hadoop_accounts; do
  echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}"
  echo "${hadoop_accounts%%:*}" >&3
done < <(grep -v 'no lock no remove' <hadoop_accounts.txt) 3>>missing_flags.txt
```

Comment: What's strange is I was definitely using syntax similar to what I have now and it was working. Then I went to modify my grep search terms and it broke after that, but I had forgotten what I did before.

Thanks for your quick and detailed response and the performance improvements.


EDIT: Ah yep, I was missing <<<"$hadoop_accounts", but I like the other way you suggested much more. I'm rather new to shell scripting so again it's much appreciated!